# SQL query execution order

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

If I have a `LINQ` query like this:

```
query.OrderBy(e => e.Name).Where(e => e.Name.Contains("Test")).Take(10);
```

What would be the execution order of `ORDERBY`, `WHERE` and `TAKE`.

1. Is `ORDERBY` done only on records that match the search criteria or on the whole table?
2. Will it search whole table for search criteria and then do `TAKE 10 records` or it will stop search when it gets 10 records that match criteria?

Comment: You could answer yourself just running it.

Comment: Read from left to the right, it is how query composed. So `Take` is last operator which applied to whole query.

Comment: https://www.sisense.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations/

Comment: Run the generated sql on SSMS and look at the execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurs in this order -

WHERE predicate is used to filter results,

THEN ORDER BY to sort and

THEN 10 from that, which happens to be TOP 10 syntax.

You could easily see how its executed in SQL Server by running the query with "INCLUDE ACTUAL EXECUTION PLAN" on.

[image]

Here is the query i used to demonstarte plus the output. Sorry had to use Ozar's tool as getting the image here on SO might be annoying.

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1v7h-q6D

Comment: Maybe illustrate the `easily see` part?

Comment: OK Sure let me edit the post with a query plan

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Done, but used Ozar's paste the plan for ease of use/better visibility/presentation.

Comment: Also, sorry just used whatever query was in the open SSMS editor, prolly no the best one to display lol

Answer (score 4):

Behind the hood that linq code is a SQL query. In SQL, you don't get to choose *how* the query is executed. This is a *descriptive* language, where you tell the database *what* results you want, and you let it figure out the most efficient way to do.

There are mental paths that we relate to to understand SQL code (like: the `from` clause is executed first, then the `where` clause, then `group by` if any, then `select` and finally `order by`) - but the database does not necessarily follows that schema. Execution plans are usually built as directed acyclic graphs, that offer much more flexibility.

Comment: No, the definition of the query makes a difference. So `Where().Take(10)` results in a `TOP` with `WHERE`. Whereas the reverse results in a derived table with `TOP` on the inside, `WHERE` on the outside

Comment: @Charlieface: the LINQ code influences the SQL query that is generated, correct. My point is that it does not tell how *the database* will execute the query.

Comment: Any way we can see the query created with that linq code while debugging. one way is sql profiler but is there any other way we can see that query in visual studio while debugging?

Comment: @KamranShaid save to variable and hover over Console.WriteLine(dbContext.GetCommand(yourQuery).CommandText);

Comment: Also, SQL Server profiler is hot garbage. it should be retired / deprecated.

Comment: @KamranShahid if you're running in Debug mode, the sql statement is printed in the Output window.

Comment: Use https://www.linqpad.net to see the generated SQL query - it's very cool to get the details

Comment: Thanks @DougCoats will try to check where in output window query is printed